# Button tag onclick not working

Tags: jquery

I try to inject a button in a page and i want to make it clickable but it seems it's not working at all.

```
$(".something").append('<button style="background-image: \
-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.3, rgb(255,170,0)),\
color-stop(0.85, rgb(222,133,0)) ); height: 28px; padding-top: 5px; \
padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; \
border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; \
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;" \
type="button" onclick="alert("lelele");"><span style="color: #fff;">\
Button</span></button>');
```

I searched the web and i went trying the simplest solution: the alert function and even that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are mismatched, try escaping the inner ones.

```
onclick="alert(\'lelele\');"
```

That said, onclick is the old way of doing things, you will get cleaner code avoiding inline JavaScript (like bipen suggests).

```
$(".something")
    .append('<button class="myClass">Button</button>') // no CSS or inline JavaScript
    .on("click", "button", function() { // delegation syntax
        alert("lalala");
    });
```

[Read more about event delegation syntax here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Also move your styles to a css file! :)

Comment: This won't work, it will be unescaped in html. Should use simple quotes.

Comment: @Haelty i am confused about your statement, please detail. 
i keep the css inline because i'm not sure yet how permissions work in the chrome extension with the css, i will look further on and check your answer thank you.

Comment: You have this `$("test").append('<button onclick="alert(\"lol\");">button</button>')`. What will be appended is `'<button onclick="alert("lol");">...'`, so then `onclick` will only contain `alert(` because of the second quote. That's why you have to use simple quote... or double escaping double quotes >_>. Use bipen's solution for clarity of code ;) and there is nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: Actually this worked very fine! I was not aware of the "escaping" type of issue :)

Answer (score 3):

the problem is with escaping....

```
onclick="alert(\'lelele\');"
```

but i prefer using  on delegated event

```
 $(function(){
  $('.something').on('click','button',function(){
     alert('lelele');
  })
 });
```

this won't require the inline onclick javascript event which is hard to read and debug...

remove `onclick="alert("lelele");"` from button

Comment: +1 This is certainly a better way to go (rather than inline js inside html inside a string inside js, ugh!)

Comment: Escaping will not work with double quotes as it will be unescaped twice (js->html->js). So must be escaped simple quotes. But +1 for the delegate.

Comment: I don't understand why would i need the $(function(){ and why i don't start directly with $('.something')...

Comment: beacause..`$(function(){` is shortcode for `$(document).ready(function(){..`... keeping script inside this makes sure it is called only after the document and its element is fully loaded...i recommended youto always use this before your script..

Answer (score 0):

Use simple quotes in the onclick argument. You have to escape them because you use them as delimiter in your append function.

```
onclick="alert(\'lelele\');"
```